# FileVault blocking macOS Sierra upgrading process from OS X El Capitain

Tags: macbook-pro, filevault

I was going to upgrade to new macOS Sierra on my MacBook Air but there's a FileVault process that is encrypting all the files that doesn't allow the installation of the new OS. In the window appears a message that says FileVault encrypting and a blue thermometer under which there's written counting the remaining time that keeps going back and forth.

Is there someone that can help me to solve this problem?

If I try to disable FileVault, it says that I can disable once encryption process is ended.

[image]

I'm upgrading from OS X El Capitain version 10.11.6. When I try to stop FileVault it says I can't disable because the encryption process in still ongoing.

[image]

P.S. I don't have an engineering background, so please suggest actions what doesn't involve manipulation with code or similar. Thanks a lot!

It's really an interesting system: it's 2 days I don't switch off the pc hoping that the coding process finishes and it's still calculating the remaining time.....

Comment: What OS X version are you upgrading from? Apparently you have started the disk encryption process and then decided to do an OS upgrade. Can you attach the screenshot (cmd+shift+4+space) of the state when you try to stop the FileVault?

Answer (score 1):

It may be paused... Look in `diskutil cs list` output for "Conversion Progress" near the bottom.

```
Conversion Progress:   Paused
```

If it says "Paused" like above then on 10.11 you can use `fsck_cs` to fix it. Use the Physical Volume disk id from your diskutil output (disk0s2 in this example):

```
fsck_cs -y disk0s2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the encryption progress is completed. Afterwards you can simply install macOS Sierra on your encrypted harddisk and don't need to do anything else.

Comment: there is no way to stope Filevault once it has started?